# using eclipse for other languages than java?

Tags: eclipse, programming-languages

I came to know that eclipse can be used for other languages as well. But will it give the same comfort level as using java? Is there anybody who has used eclipse for other languages?

Comment: may be you should mark this as Community wiki as choice of IDE, editor is subjective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used Eclipse for both C/C++, Ruby, Erlang, and a few others. None of these are as tightly integrated with Eclipse as Java is, but CDT (C/C++) gives Visual Studio a good run for its money. I usually use Emacs for the other ones.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use Eclipse for many languages other than Java.  I personally use Eclipse to code in C++, Perl, PHP, and do JavaScript as well inside of it.  While it also supports plugins for connecting and executing queries against databases, I tend to prefer other options there such as Toad or Oracle SQL Developer.  There are numerous other plugins to support many other languages that you can find either through the Update Manager or a simple Google search, many of which are excellent.

As a side note, if you're not using Mylyn, you're missing out.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is used as a base for other language and tool:
for example `As3` with FlashBuilder; `PHP`, `Javascript` with Aptana studio, `C,Python`,... with other plugins, etc...

You can found [here](http://www.eclipse-plugins.info/eclipse/plugins.jsp?category=Languages) for example some plugins for other languages.

Answer (score 1):

I've used it for Javascript (jQuery): compile-time checks are a godsend to the barren lands of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

For Java developement I feel most comfortable using Eclipse.

I tried using Eclipse for coding with Python. There is [PyDev](http://pydev.org/), an Eclipse plugin that can be used to work with the Python code in Eclipse. Though PyDev provides features like Code Completion, Syntax highlighting etc, I felt comfortable to use editors like gvim or emacs rather than Eclipse
for working with Python code. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Eclipse supports many other languages.

But you knew that already when you saw http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

So, I guess that you are asking how well it supports them...

It is possible to have Eclipse without Java. Imagine taking that and then adding Java support. Compare that with CDT for C++ and - in my experience - they are pretty much the same.

Yes, Eclipse *is* slanted at Java, and I doubt that anyone will deny that, but at the same time it tries to be fair and generic and pretty much achieves it.  Any few % less other language support *doesn't matter* when you realize that no other IDE compares.

Bottom line, whatever your language, you will be hard pushed to beat Eclipse.

And that's before I get started on the myriad plugins ...

Answer (score 0):

Not only programming, debugging with Eclipse is sweet. Beside Java, the other languages I mostly work on Eclipse are PHP and Python.

Answer (score 0):

While I was working on the Eclipse Web Tools Platform (WTP) project we often said that the Java Development Tools (JDT) were the model that we referenced for features for Web related languages. I think JDT has set the bar and many other projects that implement language specific tooling try to reach the JDT bar. I don't know that any have or that copying everything about JDT is the point but I do think the Java tools are exemplary development tools.